# Accessing response body in Angular when HTTP Post fails with error 403

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I have an Angular 9 project where I perform login via a HTTP post using `HttpClient`.
If login fails, HTTP 403 is returned with a JSON response that contains the error message to be displayed on the UI.

My problem is that my error handler is always called with a simple string `Forbidden`, instead of the response body I want. How could I retrieve the response body? It is properly returned to the browser.

I have something like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class AccountService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        // ...
    )


    login(userName, userPassword) {
        return this.http.post(`login`, {user: userName, password: userPassword}); 
    }
}
```

I have a component, which simply retrieves the error returned and shows it on the UI.

```
this.accountService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
            // error is a string here
            this.alertService.error(error.errorMessage); 
            this.loading = false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display some error message from your response you can achieve this by creating an error interceptor.

[Check this](https://satyapriyamishra111.medium.com/angular-error-interceptor-4b102f938065)
[and this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-handle-http-errors-using-interceptors-5cc483103740)